# Drop down menu button isn't coloured fully and there are strange gaps in between

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to fix my drop down menu but I'm having problems with the highlighted colour and the background colour/size.

When I hover it, it is not covering the full button with orange like I want it to and, it has some grey left in it from the background where I don't want it to be.

One of the issues may be the fact I'm using 2 style sheets for mobile and computer.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li id="active"><a href="index.html" id="current">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Revelstoke</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ticker Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Snow School</a>
      <ul id="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Kids Lessons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Adult Lessons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">First Tracks</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Trail Maps</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>  
</div><!--close nav-->
```

CSS (computer):

```css
#nav {
    background-color:#eee;
    height: 33px;
    border-top: solid black 2px;
    border-bottom: solid black 2px;
    min-width: 1000px;
}

#nav #active a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #0160a2;
    padding: 5px 15px 8px 15px;
}

#nav ul {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    line-height: 24px;
}

#nav ul li a {
    display:inline;
    padding:5px 10px 8px 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#nav li ul {
    display: none;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 97px;
    height: 82px;
}

#nav li:hover li {
    font-size: 14px;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ff8a00;
    color: #000000;
}

#nav ul li ul li a{
    padding:5px;
}

#nav ul li ul li a:hover{
    padding:5px;
    width: 97px;
    height: 82px;
}
```

CSS (mobile):

```css
#nav {
    background-color:#eee;
}

#nav ul {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#nav ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    border-top: 3px solid white;
}

#nav ul li a {
    color: #000000;
    display:block;
    padding:13px 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #0096ff;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

#nav #active a {
    background-color: #01385e;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question this should be a solution http://jsfiddle.net/GcDGv/2/ (I worked only for non-mobile CSS), this is how I fixed it:

1. I removed all `height` properties from classes related to the `sub-menu`. They can be auto-calculated.
2. Change the `width` of `li` elements in `sub-menu` to `100%`, so now they will use whole area.
3. Make links in `sub-menu` as `block` elements, so margin/paddings from top and bottom will work as you want. And removed `width` and `height` properties from last style `ul li ul li a:hover`

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked completely. How can one man be so beautiful.